# Python Help: Replacing V-Lookup in Excel with Pandas merge/join

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I'm relatively new to python, and very new to pandas. My friend asked me for some help since he knows I know some programming and his company faces a difficult problem.

It seems like a simple v-lookup situation with big files. They have two files, Postage & Shipments, with multiple sheets. They have tracking numbers in **column AA** of Sheet1 in Postage. Those tracking numbers are matched with **column K** of Sheet4 in Shipping. Once they match, it returns the customer name in **column Q** from Sheet4 in Shipping, and puts that into **column AB** back in the Postage sheet next to the column I'm searching from.

Right now, all I have is the correct dataframe from the xlsx files for each workbook. I feel like I need to use either merge or join, but I'm not sure how to return column Q once I find the match in K.

Also, is there a way to insert the data back into that original excel file? Or should I just create a new dataframe and save it as an excel file?

Anything helps. Thanks so much!

```
import pandas as pd

postage = pd.read_excel('Postage.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet1')
shipments = pd.read_excel('Shipments.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet4')

postage = pd.merge(postage['Tracking number'], shipments['Customer'], on=shipments['Tracking Number'])
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. To get more traction on your question, you might consider posting code that creates a simplified problem with a subset of the data or dummy data.

Comment: merge function mostly can replace vlookup. Find how the 'on' and 'how' paramters work.